# Strange white 1-px line across site header appearing

Tags: html, css

I took out all the things that I thought could be causing this white line to appear, but it still appears.  The problem is here: http://www.problemio.com/

and the white line I am talking about is at the bottom of the dark bar on top of the page.  Any idea how I can just make it all black without any space between that bar and the body of the page?

Thanks!!

Comment: I don't see any white line. Maybe something in your eye? jk. Are you talking about the gap between header block and body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image has a line of transparent pixels under the dark part of the bar so whatever color your page under is, will be the color that shows through.

Add this to the .nav_bar block around line 114 in your main.css file

```
.nav_bar {
background-color: #313131;
}
```

Comment: I just took the exact color of that dark gray bar and added a background-color of the same color behind the image.

Answer (score 4):

It's part of the image: http://www.problemio.com/img/ui/brownbannerbar.png

[image: http://www.problemio.com/img/ui/brownbannerbar.png]

edit: Sorry, that might not make it obvious. There's a 1px transparent line across the bottom with 2 single grey pixels about 30px from both edges.

See here: A [magnified example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAbtc.png) of the left edge.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAbtc.png]

Comment: yeah I saw the 30px indent too, which is weird.  What is causing that and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: You'd edit your image and remove the bottom row of pixels, like [this](http://i.imgur.com/Ytduv.png). The best solution though? Scrap the image. It's a useless request to the server, visitors don't need it; just remove the `background-image` from .nav-bar and keep the `background-color` you just added.